# Equivalent of std::iota in .Net

Tags: .net

I'm looking for an equivalent of the C++ `std::iota` but in .Net (.Net SDK 3.1 LTS compatible)

I want to port this C++ code to .Net

```cpp
std::array<int, 10> ar;
std::iota(ar.begin(), ar.end(), -4);
```

This will create an array of int: `{-4 -3 -2 -1 0 1 2 3 4 5}`

ref: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use:

```cs
int[] ar = Enumerable.Range(-4, 10).ToArray();

foreach (int value in ar) {
  Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.range